# Exim, debug, vs tail mainlog, is there a difference?

Tags: exim

Is there a difference between running

```
exim -bdf
```

vs

```
tail -f mainlog
```

?

I am trying to see what exim is doing, so I wanted to try exim -bdf in a terminal as root

the first time i tried this, i noticed in the mainlog file

> socket bind() to port 25 for address (any IPv6) failed: Address
>   already in use:

so I killed the running daemon process, and re-execute the -bdf command in the terminal.

but the terminal is not echoing any output from exim, but tailing the exim mainlog file in a web browser window shows real-time activity.
Yet the log file is still not showing me the level of detail I want to see for the debugging of an ACL, etc., so I'm thinking I want to try the terminal debug method.

Question 1, is there a difference between what I should be seeing in the terminal window, vs what is being written to the main log, and log level is set to "all" for max logging?

Question 2, is this normal behavior for terminal window to not output anything, but the mainlog is active? If not, is there a setting I can change to see the real-time debugging of exim in the terminal?

Comment: SOLVED: I did not understand the RTFM for command line options. Thanks to answer from Esa Jokinen I now understand to chain together -bdf with -d to begin the debug output in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `exim -bdf` [command line](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_command_line.html) option alone doesn't initiate any debugging (answering your Q2).

> `-bdf` This option has the same effect as `-bd` except that it never
>   disconnects from the controlling terminal, even when no debugging is
>   specified.

The `-v` would be more similar to `tail -f mainlog`, the documentation for this option describing the difference (answering directly to your Q1):

> `-v` This option causes Exim to write information to the standard error stream, describing what it is doing. In particular, it shows the log
>   lines for receiving and delivering a message, and if an SMTP
>   connection is made, the SMTP dialogue is shown. Some of the log lines
>   shown may not actually be written to the log if the setting of
>   `log_selector` discards them. Any relevant selectors are shown with each
>   log line. If none are shown, the logging is unconditional.

**You should be using `-d<debug options>`, more precisely `-d+acl` for *ACL interpretation*.**

You could use log files for debugging purposes too, but that may require adjusting what is being logged. In current 4.x versions of Exim the setting would be [`log_selector`](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-log_files.html#SECTlogselector); ancient and now obsolete 3.x versions had much less configurable [`log_level`](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_51.html#SEC862) from 1 to 6.

Comment: wait, the d in -bd is not the debug flag? so i'd need to do -bd -d to add the debug command? duh me dumb.

Comment: oh yeah, now the debug is working in the terminal! exim -bdf -d+all

Comment: Running `exim -bdf -d+all` shows me a startup banner, but when I run `mail -s test root <test` nothing is printed.  However the mail is still externally delivered through `/etc/aliases`.  How do I debug `exim` when sending mails out locally like this (because I have a script where `mail` works when I run the script from commandline, but not when it runs from `cron`.  Same script.  Same `mail` commandline.  AFAICS only `env` differs).

Comment: By trial and error I found the culprit:  When running from `cron` (testing with `env -i` to rule out environment) the message line length exceeded 1000 bytes (it did not when testing from commandline).  Any line length above 998 triggered this behavior.  Apparently my `exim` is unable to process lines longer than 998 bytes (presumably the buffer is 1000 bytes and 998 bytes + CR + LF + NUL no more fits).  Solution:  Use something like `cat data | fold -w900 | mail -s "subject" test@example.com` where `cat data` is a producer like `cat <<<TEXT` ;)